# Spring restful service not being found. NoClassDefFound when integrated with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am doing some tests in Spring and encountered an issue while trying to build a simple REST api. The environment is quite simple however I want to be able to do both methods of deployment, within Tomcat and within Spring Boot.

In my main project I created this class:

```
package springTest.tomcat;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SpringTest {

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name",required=true) String name){
        return "Hello "+name;
    }
}
```

And I created an application-context.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="controller" class="springTest.tomcat.SpringTest" />
</beans>
```

My application has the DynamicWebProject facet so I exported the springTest.war to tomcat 8 and started it, running on port 9090.

I then navigated to  localhost:9090/springTest/greeting?name=Aaron  but I get a 404 error.

I then tried to create another project, which would encapsulate the previous project as a Spring boot application

The only contents of this new project are as follows

```
package springTest.Boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTest.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public springTest.tomcat.SpringTest springTest(){
        return new springTest.tomcat.SpringTest();
    }
}
```

When I try to execute this however I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<init>(GenericApplicationContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:528)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at springTest.Boot.SpringTest.main(SpringTest.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Here is my pom.xml for the core application

```
<properties>
    <spring.core.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
    <spring.web.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.web.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source />
                <target />
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.web.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.web.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the pom.xml for my spring boot application

```
<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source />
                <target />
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SpringTest_Tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringTest_Tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**tl;dr**

Basically:
If i make a spring application and run from within tomcat I keep getting 404's for my REST calls.

If i encapsulate it in a SpringBoot applicaction I get a NoClassDefFoundError for a spring class that is there in the dependencies...

Repo containing the code:
https://github.com/mangusbrother/SpringTests

Comment: you are clearly in a dependency hole... just try to get yourself out of there..

Comment: reduced the dependencies to only the required. still getting the same issues.

Comment: hehe. i don't believe you

Comment: pom.xml is updated in the question.....

Comment: try update `<spring.core.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.core.version>` with `<spring.core.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.core.version>`

Comment: That solved the stack trace when starting from spring boot, however  when I try to connect from within tomcat I still get a 404, if i connect to the spring boot application i get a perpetual Loading...

Comment: i don't believe you again :D

Comment: i have to say this is a mess...you have two modules with 2 classes of name `SpringTest`, different versions for spring-web and spring-core, `@RestController` on `SpringTest` yet declared it in both xml and java configuration...you'd better follow spring's official guide first.

Comment: the XML configuration and the Java configuration are two different applications. The Java implementation is simply a wrapper around the non-spring boot application.  For more clarity and people to actually believe what I say, here is the repository [https://github.com/mangusbrother/SpringTests](https://github.com/mangusbrother/SpringTests)

Answer (score 0):

the first app doesn't have spring configuration, which you can see clearly by comparing your code with example on spring.io.
for the second, i guess it's because spring-boot has a different version of spring-core.
you should start from following [the official guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), before doing such an experiment

Comment: The first app has the application-context.xml and the second isn't loading spring core itself.

Comment: you don't have a dedicated web.xml nor web mvc config in the 1st app, there's no way to start it in a container. the 2nd depends on the SprintTest_Tomcat app, which has a spring-core dependency. now you know it _isn't loading spring core itself_, no wonder there's a `ClassNotFoundException` for a class in spring-core

Comment: the NoClassDef error was solved by updating the SpringTest_Tomcat app spring.core version to 4.1.0. And even without a web.xml or web mvc config the SpringTest_Boot app should still work, albeith the Tomcat app not working on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because some dependency of your maven project is dependent of an 'spring-core' earlier version 4.1. To discover it, I ran the following maven command:

```
c:\myapp>mvn dependency:tree
```

A maven tree (at the final of this post) shows me that the dependency 'org.springframework.shell:spring-shell:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE' has a dependency to 'org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE' that is causing this problem (version 4.0.3 is earlier than 4.1). In my case, the solution was exclude this 'sub-dependecy' at my pom.xml as follows:

```
...
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.springframework</artifactId>
                    <groupId>spring-context-support</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
....
```

This was my maven dependency tree output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building console 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ console ---
[INFO] br.com.mycompany.myapp:console:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- br.com.mycompany.myapp:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:jar:4.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] +- br.com.mycompany.myapp:hibernateRepo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.3.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- br.com.mycompany.myapp:hsqldb-repo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.shell:spring-shell:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jline:jline:jar:2.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.11:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9:compile
[INFO]
```

end.